# Precision TouchPad Absolute Position

Tags: windows, api

**Precision TouchPad**

It's a TouchPad Specification in which TouchPad sends the raw touchpad data to Windows itself. Windows is responsible for reading the input and processing the gestures.

**My Problem**

I need to find absolute position of the finger on the touchpad, That is NOT the mouse location on the screen

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site.

Comment: Is that OK now?? @vatavale

Comment: Thank you. Do you had some research? Give some details to the community.

Comment: Precision TouchPad lacks API right now, vote here to let Microsoft know we need it: https://aka.ms/Uun1l5